# How to refresh the folder icon instantly in Windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am now programming a small tool and need to refresh the folder icon instantly.
As we know, in Windows, we could modify folder icons by the following steps manually:

1. right click the folder
2. choose "customize" tag
3. click "change icon"

I also know how to set the desktop.ini file to modify its icon. But it takes really a long time to refresh (about 30 seconds).

I wanna know if there is a common way to solve it instantly no matter using C/C++ or script. Or Windows never provides a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This small C program will do the job:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

const char folderpath[] = "C:\\Your-Folder";

int main() {
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, folderPath, NULL);
}
```

`folderpath` is the full path to the folder whose icon is to be updated
Following sequence of operations works fine here (Windows 10 64 bits):

**Desktop.ini file**

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll,12
```

1. Create a folder X
2. Copy the Desktop.ini file above into the folder. The icon of the X folder will not change
3. Run the small C program above
4. The new icon is displayed on the X folder
5. Remove the Deskop.ini file created at point 2. The icon of the X folder will not change
6. Run the small C program above
7. The original folder icon is displayed on the X folder

Check the [`SHChangeNotify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118(v=vs.85).aspx) function for more details.

Comment: It would be worth a try if `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, folderPath, NULL);` is sufficient. Should be more efficient than invalidating the whole icon cache when only one icon changed. Found at [OldNewThing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150903-00/?p=91671).

Comment: Yesterday I played around with `SHCNE_UPDATEITEM` but couldn't get consistent results. Sometimes it would update the folder icon, sometimes not. I also tried to add `SHCNF_FLUSH` and `SHCNE_UPDATEDIR` but the result was still unreliable.

Comment: I did some further tests where I found that the supposed "catch all" `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` is unreliable aswell. But [SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440996/7571258) always updates the icon immediately (despite being a deprecated API since Win XP SP3)!

Comment: I searched and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini which links here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmakesystemfoldera and tested it: After giving my still default looking folder the desktop.ini file, I used "attrib +S" ON THE FOLDER. And instantly, I saw the folder with icon in an already open explorer window. Removed the flag again - folder looked default. Is this viable!?!? E.g. "dir" command does NOT show that folder any longer (by default). :P

Comment: I also used `SHChangeNotify()` and it's not reliable in Win10. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. It doesn't change it immediately but takes 1 minutes or so.

Comment: or you may use the nuget package[windows Icon Changer] which provides utility methods to deal with the problem
 [Disclaimer- I'm the author https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nakshatra.Windows.IconChanger/