# How to use SHChangeNotify via ctypes or PyWin32

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

The following is a small C program I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922397/16130983) on Stack Overflow.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

const char folderpath[] = "C:\\Your-Folder";

int main() {
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, folderPath, NULL);
}
```

How can I write something similar in Python?

Comment: Beware, not to forget *argtypes* and *restype*: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Answer (score 3):

I found this using `ctypes`:

```py
import ctypes

shell32 = ctypes.OleDLL('shell32')
shell32.SHChangeNotify.restype = None
event = SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = 0x08000000
flags = SHCNF_IDLIST = 0x0000
shell32.SHChangeNotify(event, flags, None, None)
```

When used the File Explorer refreshes but it takes a minute to update the folders. I don't know if it's working or not.